# Inverse Trigonometry doubt.

Tags: trigonometry

Suppose $\sin y=\sin 2x$, then what will be the solution for $y$?

Will it be $y=2x$ or $y=n\pi-2x$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Without additional information both are correct.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Use  $\sin(\pi-2x)=\sin 2x$ and $\sin(2m\pi+z)=\sin z$ where $m$ is any integer

so, $y=2m\pi+2x$ and $y=2m\pi+\pi-2x=(2m+1)\pi-2x$

which can be merged as $y=n\pi+(-1)^n(2x)$  where $n$ is any integer

Comment: Yes, thanks. I got that.

Comment: @AdityaParson, thanks, nice to hear that.